# ubuntu apt-get upgrade error

Tags: apt, kubuntu

when I use `apt-get install` on kubuntu-desktop ,I get an error like this:

> E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11 Resource
>   temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock the download directory

Why did this happene and how can I solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for 2 reasons

1. Another program(like software centrum) is checking for updates
2. Somehow you interrupted aptitude while it was busy(ctrl + c, or powerloss etc)

If you are sure you nothing else is running aptitude(`ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep`), delete the lockfile

`sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`